# Controls say ... in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, user-controls

I'm trying to increase my knowledge on javafx, but running into some troubles with the controls. They are often not wide enough and say ... instead of a desired string. I've attempted to use the setWidth method but this does not work. In this specific case I'm referring to choiceboxes.

[image: My program at the moment]

This is a standard javafx program, and I've done this code in the start method. The choicebox is inside of a GridPane. Here's a sample code that recreates the issue.

```
//imports
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

//main class
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
//main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //set title for window
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    //create a new button & format it
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    //give button a set action (print hello world)
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });
    //create gridpane to hold button
    GridPane root = new GridPane();

    //establish gridpane
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
       root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < 30; x++){
       root.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(20));
    }
    //set constraints, add button to gridpane
    root.setConstraints(btn,3,3);
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    //set scene and show
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding this node to a GridPane, you probably need to extend the node across multiply columns. [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

> add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)
>   Adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column,row position and spans.

```
gridPane.add(accounts, 0, 0, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think the grids would cut off a control at their intersection but that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, would I be able to do this in using setConstraints?

Comment: Yep, both do the same thing.